# MongoDB: How can I store the following relation?

Tags: mongodb

I am an IT student and we are only learning RDBMS at university. I want to get in touch with MongoDB and develop a small video game collection manager for educational purpose only.

I want to have an overview of the available platforms, which are stored. E.g

- PC
- Xbox
- Xbox 360
- Playstation

and so on

When on of the platforms is selected i want to query for all entries matching the selected platform.

So my first idea is to have to collections: platform and game

platform:

```
_id : "PLATFORMID"
name : platform_one
```

game:

```
_id : "SOMEID"
name : game_One
publisher : somePublisher
platform : PLATFORMID
```

I know it is a best practice to write as much into a document as possible, but I think in this case it is not ideal, because to get all available platforms, I must query for all games and then iterate over the whole collection and pick out the platforms.

With my approach it would be possible to load only the platforms on startup, and then query for all the games.

Am i right or is there a much better solution with MongoDB?

Since this is my first project using a NoSql DB, any help or tips are appreciated.

Comment: I think using two collections as you suggest will work fine.

Comment: In addition, assuming that platform name is unlikely to change, I'd just advice using platform name rather than id in second collection.

Answer (score 0):

Before you design you schema I would recommend reading this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/ because it will give you good ideas as to what the different data models in mongo are.  This will create a firm foundation of how to do things in Mongo (which is very different then a traditional RDB).

Mongo schema is highly use case dependent and therefor the data structure is tightly integrated with the program.  Don't think that is necessary to completely normalize your data, which usually isn't the right approach when using mongo.  Also be aware that once that is true, there are many different schema structures to pick from, and often the performance needed is how that choice is made.  Therefor two applications with the exact same data may have entirely different data structures and both are correct for their use case, and it would incorrect for them to use the others (if you like performance anyway).
For your specific case I would suggest putting the platform field into the game document.  To get all the platforms there are a couple of approaches.
First option: have a collection that has all platforms in it.  These can be stored in the _id field and be it's only contents, or you can have additional fields about that platform.  These platforms will be unique and the program logic will have to keep it updated.  Perhaps the application only offers platforms as a pick list from this collection when creating documents for the games collection.  This will allow many clients to keep in sync over the platforms offered cheaply.  Be aware there are no foreign keys so the program itself must keep these collections in sync.
Second option: Use distinct: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/.  This will return the distinct values of a query.  In this specific case:

db.runCommand({distinct: "game", key: "platform", query: {} })

However on large collections to get a static set of data, this can be overly expensive.  So if the key is relatively fixed it is likely better to use the first option.  If the key can mutate between queries then this option is best.

Best,
Charlie